# Agree to my privacy policy when sign up to my site via facebook

Tags: facebook, licensing, privacy-policy

My site has privacy policy and terms of service, when user registered required to agree to both of them. But also I have option of sign up with facebook.
Do user required to agree to my privacy policy and terms of service when signing up to my site with facebook?

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking. Do you mean if users automatically agree to your site’s policy, when the use your FB app to login? Not by default, I think. But you can add your site’s policy URL as your app’s policy URL in your app settings, then it will show up as link in the login dialog. (Just make sure it covers both then, policy for your app and your site.)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe if you will add your comment as answer I will able to check it as right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users don’t automatically agree to your site’s policy, when the use your FB app to login.

But you can add your site’s policy URL as your app’s policy URL in your app settings, then it will show up as link on the bottom of the login dialog. I think that by logging in to an app users are expected to be agreeing to the policy linked to in the login dialog.